# How to access variable in a function expression nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Is there a way to get the contents of variable `data` outside the function. I am so stuck, looked various forums in stackoverflow and but failed. I am trying to retrieve data from mongoose model and push those results into an array `results` and when i print `results` array, i get empty array .

```
  var results = []
  Model.find({firstName:name}, function(err,data){       
     if(err)
       throw err;

     data.forEach(function(element) {
       console.log(element);
       results.push(element);
     });
 });
 console.log(results) --> []
```

But when i try to print the data inside the `ForEach`, I am was get the results, listed below.

```
0 => { _id: 5dc9953a2168993711903698,
  id: 763,
  firstName: 'Deepak',
  lastName: 'Kalra',
  image_id: 'No',
  logged: false,
  __v: 0 
}
1 => { 
  _id: 5dc995546f0f88372080ea36,
  id: 511,
  firstName: 'Deepak',
  lastName: 'Kalra',
  image_id: 'No',
  logged: false,
  __v: 0 
}
```

## Entire code

```
  alexa.intent("FirstName", {
     "slots": { "name": "AMAZON.FIRST_NAME" },
     "utterances": [
       "sure {-|name}","{-|name}","my name is {-|name}"
      ]
  },
  function(request, response) {
    var name = 'Deepak';
    try {
      var results = await Model.find({firstName:name});
      console.log(results)
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle error.
    }

   // Model.find({firstName:name}, function(err,data){

      //   if(err)
      //     throw err;
     //   data.forEach(function(element) {
    //     console.log(element);
    //     results.push(element);
     //   });
  // });

     console.log(results);
  });
```

Is there any solution to fix it. please help me

Comment: To understand what's happening, I recommend you read about Asynchronous JavaScript.

Comment: Is the solution to the above problem achievable @Samuel

Comment: Yes, It's the reason why you have this confusing situation. JavaScript is naturally like that. Take a look at Dijkstra's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, `console.log(results)` executed before `Model.find` was finished.

Two things you can do here:

- Put `console.log(results)` inside the callback.
- Use `async/await` to get similar behaviour.

Example (callback):

```
Model.find({firstName:name}, function(err,data){       
    if(err)
      throw err;

    console.log(data); // data is already an array
});
```

Example (async/await):

```
try {
  var results = await Model.find({ firstName: name });  
  console.log(results)
} catch (error) {
  // Handle error.
}
```

`Model.find` already returns an array of document, so you don't have to run a loop to push them into an array.

**UPDATED**

```
alexa.intent("FirstName", {
  "slots": { "name": "AMAZON.FIRST_NAME" },
  "utterances": [
    "sure {-|name}", "{-|name}", "my name is {-|name}"
  ]
},
async function (request, response) {
  var name = 'Deepak';
  try {
    var results = await Model.find({ firstName: name });
    console.log(results)
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle error.
  }
});
```

Notice the `async` in front of function.

Comment: Thanks for the response. When i try to modify according to what you have written, i am getting  SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function @Dijkstra

Comment: That is how it work. Your function has to be `async` to `await` a promise. I believe you are not familiar with it. Could you provide the full function instead of this snippet?

Comment: The function i am using is available in the link https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find

Comment: I asked you to provide the whole code not this this few lines.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I have posted the complete code. @Dijkstra

Comment: Mark as accepted would help.